# Recovering persistent data from a live USB

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I created a live Lubuntu USB drive with persistent storage, but now I'd like to use it for a different purpose and wipe all of the data on it. Is there a way to copy all the data on a different USB drive or on a hard drive? Would copying and pasting all the content on the USB drive work?

Comment: It's unclear the purpose of your question. Are you trying to save only the contents of the persistent file system? That should be easy to do from the running system. Or the purpose is to use the stick temporarily for other purposes? If so it can be cloned to file using any software for that purpose. Later the image file can be used (with the same software) to restore everything as it was.

Comment: I'd like to save the whole content (Lubuntu+the changes I've made, the files I've created). I'll be using the stick for other purporses temporarily, since I will probably put a persistent version of Lubuntu back on it later. Can you name specific software?

Comment: Clonezilla is free and open-source and does the job perfectly. Better to boot it as standalone - they provide ISOs that can be burned to USB or CD - and have everything connected already, the source and the target.

Comment: It looks like Clonezilla clones an OS that is already installed on the computer, whereas I'd like to clone what's on a USB drive. Have I just not understood how Clonezilla works?

Comment: It clones anything you want, like any other similar software.

Comment: With a persistent flash drive all changes and updates are saved in casper-rw file or partition. The file can be copied using "Files" copy paste and the partition can be copied using "GParted". The new path to "/home" must be noted in /etc/fstab.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I don't need it anymore (did what I wanted without clearing the USB drive), but thank you anyway! I'll probably need it in the future